# Adding index in each array element of javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
[2003, 5010, 4006, 5007, 2003, 5010]
```

I am using this instruction to extract specific column and it gives the above output

```
// profiles is a multidimensional array
var pofileIds   =   profiles.map((el) => el.TargetProfileId)
```

Now i want an output like this

```
[{ ids : 2003}, { ids : 5010 },{ ids : 4006 },{ ids : 5007 },{ ids : 2003 }]
```

Or this

```
ids=2003&ids=5010&ids=4006&ids=5007&ids=2003
```

I am working on existing project and can't change this. I need to call asp.net services to return me the desired data. The application is working on web and i am working to convert it to mobile but i am bound to use same services for mobile as web.

Comment: What is `(el) => el.TargetProfileId`? That doesn't look like Javascript. Is it Coffeescript?

Comment: why not simplly loop array and create the required format?

Comment: @Barmar it is indeed javascript you can test on fiddle

Comment: looping is not a problem but i wanted a simple instruction as i have php background

Comment: @Barmar: [“Arrow functions”](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/) are a new feature introduced in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @CBroe and not supported on most browsers without "new features" being explicitly enabled.

Comment: @raheelshan so what browser are you testing this on, and with what settings?

Comment: and do you intend this code to be portable to other browsers?

Comment: i am making this for mobile not for browsers

Answer (score 1):

When i use `(el) => ...` I get an error.
Try like this

```
var arr = [2003, 5010, 4006, 5007, 2003, 5010];

var profileIds = arr.map(function (elem) {
    return { "ID": elem };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
profiles.map(el => ({ ids: el.TargetProfileId }))
```

From [Understanding ECMAScript 6 arrow functions](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/):

> Because curly braces are used to denote the function’s body, an arrow function that wants to return an object literal outside of a function body must wrap the literal in parentheses.

Comment: You should have said so in the question. What problem does it produce?

Comment: displays values as undefined

Comment: I've modified my answer based on reading the arrow function examples. When the arrow function returns an object, you need to wrap it in parentheses, because otherwise the curly braces are interpreted as denoting the function body.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers you gave and for you time. By the way i have found some simple solution for this which i am posting here.

Here is my array

```
[2003, 5010, 4006, 5007, 2003, 5010]
```

First i used this instruction from user jsonscript. But i had to modify it a little

```
var pofileIds   =   profiles.map((el) => { return { "ids": el.TargetProfileId }})
```

This produces this result

```
[Object {ids=2003}, Object {ids=5010}, Object {ids=4006}, Object {ids=5007}, Object {ids=2003}, Object {ids=5010}]
```

Then using jquery `$.param`

```
pofileIds   =   pofileIds.map((el) => $.param(el) )
```

Output

```
["ids=2003", "ids=5010", "ids=4006", "ids=5007", "ids=2003", "ids=5010"]
```

And finally javascript join

```
pofileIds   =   pofileIds.join("&")
```

Output

```
ids=2003&ids=5010&ids=4006&ids=5007&ids=2003&ids=5010
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

With pure JS should be very easy:

```
var myArray= [2003, 5010, 4006, 5007, 2003, 5010],
myObject,
myResponse = [];
for (var index in myArray)
{
    myObject = new Object();
    myObject.ids = myArray[index];
    myResponse.push(myObject);
}

//Output in the console for double check
console.log (myResponse);
```

Comment: don't use `for ... in ...` on arrays!

Comment: You can use for (var index =0 ; index < myArray.length ; index++) if you prefer, I was not 100% sure how this array was built, so this will cover all the possible scenarios, but you are right, if hash tables are not used, it is better no to use for ... in

Comment: it's not a question of "preference", using `for ... in` is fundamentally _incorrect_.

Comment: Then how do you iterate an array in this way? myArray['monday'] = 10, myArray['tuesday'] = 20;

Comment: if you're using string keys, then those are _properties_ of the object, not array elements.